# What type of water pipe and bushing is this called?

Tags: outdoorfaucet

[image: Garden hose reel attached to wall with feed pipe mounted using spacers]

Anyone know what kind of pipe this would be to mount to wall for permanent water line? Also trying to find the rubber bushing where it mounts.

Comment: looks like a pneumatic fitting

Comment: That elbow looks like same as what I have for my hydraulic hoses/pipes.  Is this picture from more of rural/farm area?

Comment: Looks like compression-fittings on stainless-steel tubing. Possibly Swagelok® possibly some other brand. Thus, not threaded pipe.

Comment: The pic you provided is great as an overview. A closer pic of the pipe and bracket in question may help get you answers instead of educated guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Since the pipe and bracket are not included with the hose reel, we can only speculate. It's a custom installation. My guess is the pipe is stainless steel. It could be aluminum but aluminum but aluminum isn't usually used for potable water supplies. The bracket would be a cushion bracket made of stainless steel for wall mounting.

Comment: I did some more digging and the clamps appear to be maybe beta clamps used in hydraulic applications but I can’t find the exact part. The pipe must be custom length threaded stainless

Comment: @LawnMavrik  Probably having the exact part is not as important than having one that fits.  Drill two holes in a steel plate, wrap pipe in some rubber, and mount to a wall, will do the same job.  Looks like the person who did this, used some parts he had handy.